# Jasper Report parameter returns wrong results

Tags: reporting, jasper-reports

I'm writing a report to get result from mysql database. The query has one parameter which is of type int in mysql database. I define a parameter of type java.lang.Integer but when I run the report and give it a value it doesn't return any data. I tried to change the parameter type to String, then I got  incorrect results. Here is the report query:

```
    SELECT
     orders.`number` AS orders_number,
     orders.`length` AS orders_length,
     orders.`thick` AS orders_thick,
     orders.`date` AS orders_date,
     orders.`weight` AS orders_weight
FROM
     `orders` orders
WHERE
     orders.`customer_id` = $P{cust_id}
```

and here is the Order table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `thick` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_fk` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the `$P{}` syntax for `$P!{}`. As in,

```
WHERE
    orders.`customer_id` = $P!{cust_id}
```

Jasper usually works by converting the query to a java PreparedStatement object, then setting the parameters using the object's methods. The `$P!{}` syntax will do the parameter substitution before the query is converted to an object.